# Postgresql regex match string with substring

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a string `foo,bar` what i want to do is to form a query matching both of them (can have gap between them)

for example it should be matching against entries like

```
aaa,bbbb,foo,zzz,bar
bar,ccc,ddddd,foo,iiiii
```

but not

```
aaa,eeeee,foo,rrrrrr,hhhhhh
ooooo,ii,sssss,bar,xxxx
```

the column that i'm trying to matching against is of type `text`

i tried doing it like this

`select * from string_entries where str similar to '%(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)%';`

but i'm getting this error

```
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
SQL state: 2201B
```

Comment: select str from string_entries where str similar to '%foo%' AND str similar to '%bar%';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am inclined to not do this with a regex comparison, but convert the string into an array:

```
select *
from string_entries 
where string_to_array(str, ',') @> array['foo', 'bar']
```

This will only work if you need equality comparison. If you wanted to also match using e.g. `foo%` rather than `foo` then this would work.

Comment: Hi, can I ask what `where string_to_array(str, ',') @> array['foo', 'bar']` means?

Comment: @RyszardCzech: `string_to_array` converts the string to an array (hence the name). The `@>` operator then tests of the array on the right side is contained in the array on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these values must appear as *full* comma-separated entries, you can use

```
where str ~ '^(?=.*(?:,|^)foo(?:,|$))(?=.*(?:,|^)bar(?:,|$))'
```

Here, it will match strings that contain `foo` and `bar` in any order using the `~` (regex matching) operator. *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*(?:,|^)foo(?:,|$))` - immediately on the right, there should be any zero or more chars, as many as possible, and then a `foo` string (either at the start of string or right after a comma and followed with a comma or end of string position)
- `(?=.*(?:,|^)bar(?:,|$))` - immediately on the right, there should be any zero or more chars, as many as possible, and then a `bar` string (either at the start of string or right after a comma and followed with a comma or end of string position)

Assuming these values must appear as *whole words* you can replace the non-capturing groups with `\y` word boundaries and use

```
where str ~ '^(?=.*\yfoo\y)(?=.*\ybar\y)'
```

See the [online DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=19362d257bb5b6c297aadd277eba9421):

```
CREATE TABLE string_entries
    (str character varying)
;

INSERT INTO string_entries
    (str)
VALUES
    ('aaa,bbbb,foo,zzz,bar'),
    ('bar,ccc,ddddd,foo,iiiii'),
    ('aaa,eeeee,foo,rrrrrr,hhhhhh'),
    ('ooooo,ii,sssss,bar,xxxx')
;

select str from string_entries where str ~ '^(?=.*(?:,|^)foo(?:,|$))(?=.*(?:,|^)bar(?:,|$))';
```

[image]

Comment: This ignores word boundaries. How about `aaa,foobar,bbb`?

Comment: @ceving Fair enough, I focused on fixing `'%(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)%'`. I fixed the solution to account for comma-separated values.

Comment: @ceving I think the two solutions should suffice.